# PHP Move array elements after array unset

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to move some array elements. I have 4 arrays containing elements from a website.

I had to unset a few elements from 3 of the arrays as they contain inaccurate information. The problem however is that each element of the 4 arrays is linked. for example array 1 contains information containing the name of an event, array 2 has information about the date of an event. For this reason, their indexes must match.

I currently have this situation

Array 1: 0: Event name 1: event name 2: 3: 4: event name

Array 2: 0: event date 1: 2: 3: event date

essentially I need to push the elements into the blanks space so they can be iterated over and their elements inserted into a database, however they must be inserted together as they correspond to make a more whole piece of information. so ideally they will end up like this...

Array 1: 0: event name 1: event name 2: event name etc etc

Array 2: 0:event date 1: event date 2: event date etc etc

Thank you for the help, apoligies if my explanation was unclear!

Comment: So where is event date 2 stored now (in your example)? What's the key in array 2 where the event date 2 is stored?

Comment: wouldn'T it be ideal to end up like this: `array(0 => array('name' => 'event 1 name', 'date' => 'event 1 date'), 1 => array('name' => 'event 2 name', 'date' => 'event 2 date') ... )` so you can iterate over an array where every array item holds and array representing one array?

Comment: Also, maybe do provide some code. What did you try? How do you retrieve your data and so on ..